# XSLT Contains function

Tags: xml, xslt, average, contains

I want to do three things, show the amount of cars that are older and younger than 1999, show the average price range between the cars (the year). And also extract the amount of cars which contain the text automatic in adtext parameter of the XML. This is how far I've gotten.

My XML structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Uppgift3.xsl"?>
<autoads>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Honda</name>
        <model>XL 1000 V</model>
        <regyear>2001</regyear>
        <price>129900</price>
        <adtext>2001 Honda XL 1000 V, 8.900 km. hög vindruta. Pris 129.900kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Nissan</name>
        <model>Almera 1.4S</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>119000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Nissan Almera 1.4S, 5 dörrar, met, 70.000 km. el.spegel/fönster, galv. kaross, c.lås, startspärr, airbag, nedfällb. baks. ABS, ute temp. R/CD, alarm, d.fäste, v.säten, s/v-hj.  EU-godk. full service, servo. Pris 119.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>5 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Mercedes-Benz</name>
        <model>C220 Elegance</model>
        <regyear>1995</regyear>
        <price>209000</price>
        <adtext>1995 Mercedes-Benz C220 Elegance, 4 dörrar, 88.000 km. skinn, klima/automatic, cruise, el.spegel/fönster, alu.fälgar, c.lås, airbag, antispinn,  ABS, ute temp, radio, s/v-hjul, servo, creme skinn. automat. Pris 209.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>S8</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>850000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Audi S8, 4 dörrar, 40.000 km. 4x4, Tiptronic-aut., klimataut., ABS, el.fönster/speglar/säten, soltak, c.lås, servo, airbag, startspärr, antispinn, cruise., alu., träinred., sort skinn, mitttarmstöd., sportssäten, stereo, alarm, s/v-hjul, dragkrok, 17"+18"alu. Pris 850.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Yamaha</name>
        <model>Thunderace 1000</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>130000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Yamaha Thunderace 1000, 11.500 km. Röd/Silver,tankväska medföljer. 146hk Pris kan diskuteras vid snabb affär. Pris 130.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>A4 1.6</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>260000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Audi A4 1.6, 4 dörrar, 78.000 km. el.fönster, ABS, alu. airbag, , klima, ESP, navig. plus, TV, evt. inbyte, power box (+30 HK) medföljer. Pris 260.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Jeep</name>
        <model>Grand Cherokee 2.5TD</model>
        <regyear>0</regyear>
        <price>359000</price>
        <adtext>0 Jeep Grand Cherokee 2.5TD, Stv., 38.000 km. A/C, el.fönster/spegel, 8xalu., c.lås, airbag, R/CD, s/v-hjul, servo. Pris 359.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>TL 1000 R</model>
        <regyear>1998</regyear>
        <price>110000</price>
        <adtext>1998 Suzuki TL 1000 R, 8400 km. Pris 110.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Volkswagen</name>
        <model>Golf 1.8 Pink Floyd</model>
        <regyear>1994</regyear>
        <price>85000</price>
        <adtext>1994 Volkswagen Golf 1.8 Pink Floyd, 4 dörrar, 135.600 km. Eu-godkänd, airbag, el.taklucka, just ratt, metallic, radio/CD/Kass, s/v-hjul, servicebok, servo, stereo. Fullständig service, 1 ägare, 6 högtalare. Pris 85.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Volvo</name>
        <model>850 2.0 LT</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>245490</price>
        <adtext>1997 Volvo 850 2.0 LT, Stv., 122785 km. halvskinn, el.spegel/fönster/soltak, fj.c.lås, st.spärr, airbag, just.ratt, rails, nedf.baksäte, m.armstöd, ABS, rad/kass, alarm, dragkrok, s/v-hjul, f.glass, met, garanti, servo. Pris 245.490 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>A3 1.6 Ambition</model>
        <regyear>1998</regyear>
        <price>180000</price>
        <adtext>1998 Audi A3 1.6 Ambition, 3 dörrar, 88.000 km. s/v-hj. el.fönster, ABS, f.glass, alu. c.lås, servo, airbag, rökfri, stilig bil. Pris 180.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>3 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>BMW</name>
        <model>K 1200 RS</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>195000</price>
        <adtext>2000 BMW K 1200 RS, 4.000 km. sidoväskor, bagagefästen. Pris 195.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1200</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>Baleno 1.6 GLX</model>
        <regyear>1999</regyear>
        <price>175000</price>
        <adtext>1999 Suzuki Baleno 1.6 GLX, Stv., 49.500 km. A/C, el.fönster/speil, c.lås, airbag, rails, ABS, stereo, , servo. Pris 175.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>LS 650 Savage</model>
        <regyear>1987</regyear>
        <price>29000</price>
        <adtext>1987 Suzuki LS 650 Savage, röd. Pris 29.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>650</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>GS 500 E</model>
        <regyear>1993</regyear>
        <price>31900</price>
        <adtext>1993 Suzuki GS 500 E. Pris 31.900,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>500</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>BMW</name>
        <model>520 i</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>387000</price>
        <adtext>2000 BMW 520 i, Stv., 52.600 km. Skinn, klima, m.f.ratt, el.spegel/fönster, alu.fälgar, c.lås, airbag x 6, antispinn, rails, träint, ABS, rad/cd, alarm, dragkrok, met, servo, Pris 387.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Triumph</name>
        <model>Daytona T 595</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>115000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Triumph Daytona T 595, 13.000 km. Är som ny, karbon anlägg, nya däck, extra tank. Pris 115.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>955</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Mitsubishi</name>
        <model>Pajero 2.5 TD</model>
        <regyear>1987</regyear>
        <price>59000</price>
        <adtext>1987 Mitsubishi Pajero 2.5 TD, Stv. 4x4, dragkrok, servo, mycket utr., ingen rost. Pris 59.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
</autoads>
```

The total amount of cars that are automatic is actually a blank, got me a little confused I do believe I've used the "contains" function correctly, if not can someone put me in the right direction?
This is how my XSLT looks for the time being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/autoads">
 <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Bilar</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Antal Äldre än 1999</th>
        <th>Antal Yngre än 1999</th>
        <th>Antal Automat</th>
        <th>Genomsnitts pris för bilar äldre än 19999</th>
        <th>Genomsnitts pris för bilar ungre än 19999</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ad[regyear &lt;= '1999']/volume), '0')"/> </td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ad[regyear &gt;= '1999']/volume), '0')"/></td>
         <td><xsl:if test="contains(ad/adtext, 'automatic')">
         <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ad/volume))"/>
         </xsl:if></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ad[regyear &lt;= '1999']/price), '0.00')"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ad[regyear &gt;= '1999']/price), '0.00')"/></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Anyone else have any inputs on how I could think differently on the code above?

Comment: Why are you using `xsl:for-each` and `xsl:if`, instead of continuing what you did with the `sum()` just using `count()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of**:

> ```
>  <td>
>    <xsl:if test="contains(ad/adtext, 'automatic')">
>      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ad/volume))"/>
>    </xsl:if>
>  </td>
> ```

**one way to produce the wanted result is**:

```
     <td>
       <xsl:value-of select=
                     "format-number(sum(ad[contains(adtext, 'automatic')]/volume), '0')"/>
     </td>
```